# 403: Access is denied / Spring security

Tags: java, spring-security

Estou com prblema para trabalhar com o spring Secutiry. 
Quando adiciono esta linha abaixo, recebo status 403 quando tento acessar a url.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustonUsuarioDetailService custonUsuarioDetailService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Funciona
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/webjars/**","/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/usuarios").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                //Problema
                .antMatchers("/usuario/getIndicador").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                //
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

    }
```

Em meu controller, ja coloquei a anotação   @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")
porém esta parecendo que o security não encontra a role.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/usuario")
public class UsuarioCtrl {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    @GetMapping("getOne")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getOne(String nome) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(usuarioRepository.findFirstByNome(nome), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("getIndicador")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getIndicador() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(usuarioRepository.count(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Debugando essa classe, verifiquei q meu user está retornando um usuario com a role esperada.

```
@Component
public class CustonUsuarioDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    public CustonUsuarioDetailService(UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository) {
        this.usuarioRepository = usuarioRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        //Recupero usuario pela identificação
        Usuario usuario = Optional.ofNullable(usuarioRepository.findByIdentificacao(username)).orElseThrow(()-> new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuario não encontrado!"));
        //Recupero permissoes
        List<GrantedAuthority> permissoes = new ArrayList<>();
        permissoes.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(usuario.getTipoUsuario().name()));
        //Atribuo valores para User
        User user = new User();
        user.setAtivo(usuario.getStatus());
        user.setNome(usuario.getNome());
        user.setSenha(usuario.getSenha());
        user.setLogin(usuario.getIdentificacao());
        user.setPermissoes(permissoes);
        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Na base de dados, como está sendo cadastrado o perfil do usuário?

Comment: Obrigado Denis mas consegui resolver o problema seguindo esse video, muito boa a explicação. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MM14uwVhVhc

Answer (score 0):

O Spring Security utiliza o recurso `AccessDecisionManager` para controle dos acessos. Este recurso por sua vez implementa o `RoleVoter` padrão do próprio framework. Ao se utilizar a implementação padrão (que aparenta ser o seu caso), é preciso utilizar o prefixo "ROLE_" junto ao perfil do usuário, propriamente dito.

Uma outra forma de contornar esta situação seria customizar o controle dos acessos do Spring Security, criando o seu próprio `AccessDecisionManager`. Para isto é preciso informar ao próprio Spring Security que o gerenciador de acessos agora será o que você criou.

Segue um exemplo de como implementar o seu próprio gerenciador:

```
public class MeuGerenciadorDeAcesso  extends AffirmativeBased {
    public MeuGerenciadorDeAcesso() {
        super();
        List<AccessDecisionVoter> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<AccessDecisionVoter>();
        RoleVoter roleVoter = new MyCustomRoleVoter();
        decisionVoters.add(roleVoter);
        AuthenticatedVoter authenticatedVoter = new AuthenticatedVoter();
        decisionVoters.add(authenticatedVoter);
        setDecisionVoters(decisionVoters);
    }
}
```